# ¿Cómo colocar un Scanner a un Set en un Println?

Tags: java

Necesito saber como hacer para que en el Print me deje colocar mi metodo set con un scanner, para asi ingresar manualmente el valor de "Horas". Deseo todo eso en un mismo PRINT "Ingrese horas: **horasScanner**/**minutosScanner**

```
package practico4;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mainHoras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        Horas h;
        h = new Horas(0, 0, 0);
        System.out.print("Ingrese una hora: "+ h.setHora(sc.nextInt()));
        
    }
}
```

[image: Foto ejemplo]

Comment: Agrega el código como texto por favor, no se ve el código. saludos

Comment: Si lo piensas bien eso no tiene mucho sentido porque lo último que se ejecutaría sería la función `print`, pero antes tiene que montar la cadena a imprimir, para lo que primero tiene que ejecutar el `nextInt()`. Así que tu programa se quedaría parado sin mostrar nada esperando a que teclees un entero. Luego ejecutaría el `setHora` del objeto `h` pasándole ese entero tecleado, y si esta función `setHora` retornara algo, entonces ejecutaría el `print` con la cadena de texto que tienes,  más el resultado de la función `setHora` que me temo es nada de nada....

Comment: No hay manera de setear y mostrar al mismo tiempo? yo para que me quede todo en un mismo renglon

Comment: No. Que pongas todo en una misma línea no cambia el orden en el que se ejecutan las cosas. Ahí primero pide el dato, y luego imprime el texto.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien, lo que intentas hacer es esto:

```
System.out.print("ingrese una hora en formato hh/mm: ");
String[] horaCompleta = sc.nextLine().split("/",2);
int hora = Integer.valueOf(horaCompleta[0]);
int minutos = Integer.valueOf(horaCompleta[1]);
Horas h = new Horas(hora, minutos, 0);
System.out.print(h.imprimir());
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]